# Kubuntu: Show programs only on their workspace

Tags: kubuntu, desktop-environments, workspaces, taskbar

When switching workspaces (Virtual Desktops); is there a way to make programs **only** show up on their belonging workspace?

By default all programs are visible on the taskbar, even if the program is on a different workspace. If you click the program, it will take you to the workspace it belongs to. I do not want any programs showing up that does not belong to the current workspace I am on.

Help will be very much appreciated.

I am running on Ubuntu 18.04, with the Kubuntu Desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be configured in both the *Task Manager* and *Icons-only Task Manager*.

Right-click on the Task Manager and select **Task Manager Settings...**:

[image: Task manager context menu]

In the *General* tab, scroll down and tick the checkbox next to **Show only tasks from the current desktop**:

[image: Task manager settings]

Answer (score 0):

I know how to do this on Ubuntu regular, I guess it's the same on Kubuntu. You can stop apps on different workspaces showing on the dock by enabling the option "Isolate Workspaces" in Dash to Dock extension: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTwlC.png).
To isolate the apps while using `Super + Tab`, I used dconf Editor, and enabled the option at `/org/gnome/shell/app-switcher/current-workspace-only`: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT7Uc.png).

Comment: I am sorry, but this does not work. I should have elaborated that I am running Ubuntu 18.04, with the Kubuntu Desktop. That being said, I believe your tips will point me in the right direction. If I find out how, I will make sure to post it here.

Comment: Ok, so you have Kubuntu desktop - that means you can't use GNOME extensions. Right.